# load and invoke html file containing javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

I am writing a small application in VS2012 containing a webbrowser control. I would like to load a html file containing javascript. The webbrowser control is not able to deal with javascript default. So I have been doing some reading.

I have the following html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var centerlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.046006, -105.245867);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: centerlatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The html file located in the debug directory of my c# project (VS2012).

I would like to load this html file and call the initialize function. I have been searching for a long time on a clear tutorial on how to do this but without any success. With the knowledge I have I tried the following. However, not with the expected result.

Code:

```
maps_browser.DocumentText = File.ReadAllText("GPSmap.html");
maps_browser.Document.InvokeScript("initialize");
```

So my questions are:

1. How do I load a *.html file containing javascript into the webbrowser?
2. How do I call javascript functions from the html file?
3. How to properly navigate to the html file?

   Thanks in advance for any advice :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that the following code works for me:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        maps_webbrowser.DocumentText = File.ReadAllText(@"GPSmap.html");
    }

    private void maps_webbrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(maps_webbrowser.DocumentText.ToString());
        maps_webbrowser.Document.InvokeScript("initialize");
    }
}
```